# Sound problem on VLC

Tags: sound, 15.04, vlc

Watching videos with VLC, the sound will randomly go off (the video plays fine) and only returns if I skip to a different part of the video.

The same video files play perfectly on the built-in 'Videos' application.

I installed VLC from Synaptic, and the version is

```
$ vlc --version
VLC media player 2.2.0 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.0-0-g1349ef2)
VLC version 2.2.0 Weatherwax (2.2.0-0-g1349ef2)
Compiled by buildd on allspice.buildd (Apr  7 2015 15:17:17)
Compiler: gcc version 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu12)
This program comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
You may redistribute it under the terms of the GNU General Public Licence;
see the file named COPYING for details.
Written by the VideoLAN team; see the AUTHORS file.
```

My audio device (I seem to have two):

```
$ sudo lshw | grep -i audio -A1
description: Audio device
product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller
vendor: Intel Corporation

description: Audio device
product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
vendor: Intel Corporation
```

Is this a bug with VLC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running:

```
vlc --version
VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind (revision 2.1.6-0-gea01d28)
```

but have had this too with some files since VLC existed...

VLC is really robust, but even VLC can sometimes not correct from all errors in badly encoded files and other players might not even play the file at all!  What I do then is a:

```
nice --adjustment=18 avconv -i /path/to/file.ext -c:v libxvid -vtag XVID -g 250 -bf 2 -me_method epzs -qmax 6 -metadata title="file2.ext" -metadata artist="" -r 25 -aspect 16:9 -c:a libmp3lame -metadata title="" -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 128k /path/to/file2.ext
```

This will *transcode* the file to xvid in the same container (most of the time you will see a gazillion timing errors and corrections) and then it'll play normally.

Every now and then you'll find a file that *even with a transcode* does not play well.  Then just go back to the source (DVD/CD/Download/...) and get another copy from the source.

Comment: I tried this with a few files and it did solve the problem. However, I did find a simper solution - play them with Totem instead.  :)

Comment: That *is a solution*, but not an answer to the question!  **;-)  >:)**

Comment: Well... the actual question was "Is this a bug with VLC?"   :-p

Comment: It's a "Not-implemented-yet-because-no-one-gives-a-rats-bottom"!  :D